# Sorting, python 3

Tags: python, sorting

```
def sorting(String, List):  
    List = [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5]  
    if String == "asc":
        return List.sort() 
    elif String == "desc": 
        return List.sort(reverse=True) 
    elif String == "none": 
        return List 
res = sorting("asc", List)
print("List in ascending order: ", res)
```

This code is not working, I want it to output the list in ascending and descending order given the string is either asc or desc, and it output the list as is if the string is none. Can i get help?

Comment: `.sort()` is an in place operation, it doesn't return anything. Use `sorted`

Comment: `List.sort()` returns `None`.

Comment: Why are you passing in `List` when you do `res =sorting("asc", List)`?  Don't you mean `res = sorting("asc")`?  Why do you even have `List` as a parameter in the `sorting()` method?

Answer (score 1):

`List.sort()` sorts the list in place and returns nothing.  Your two choices are:

```
def sorting(String, List):  
    List = [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5]  
    if String == "asc":
        List.sort() 
    elif String == "desc": 
        List.sort(reverse=True) 
    return List
```

That has the unfortunate side effect of changing the original list, which doesn't really matter in this case.  The other way is to use the `sorted` function, which returns a new list in sorted order.

```
def sorting(String, List):  
    List = [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5]  
    if String == "asc":
        return sorted(List) 
    elif String == "desc": 
        return sorted(List, reverse=True) 
    return List
```